# How to center text left and right on the same line?

Tags: titles, fancyhdr, mdframed, ragged2e

I'm looking to recreate this title environment below.
[image]
I think the person used `mdframed` so I choose to use that as well. I get stuck when I try implementing the course name, professor name or week number. I thought about using `fancyhdr` for this but I'm not sure if it can be done or if it's the best option.

What do you guys this? Here's the code I've written so far.
[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\newcommand{\createtitle}{
\begin{mdframed}
[nobreak=true, % prevents page breaking
outerlinewidth=0.5pt,
innertopmargin=0.5\baselineskip,
innerbottommargin=0.75\baselineskip,
innerrightmargin=11pt,
innerleftmargin=11pt]
    \begin{center}
        \Huge\textsc{This is the Title}
    \end{center}
\end{mdframed}}
```

Comment: Use `\hfill`; as in `Week 4 \hfill UCSB 2015`.

Comment: The tricky one is **left center right** in one line.  `\noindent\rlap{left}\hfill center\hfill\llap{right}\par`  Note that it is possible to overlap the text.

Answer (score 5):

Via `Left Text\hfill Right Text`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\newcommand{\createtitle}{
\begin{mdframed}
[nobreak=true, % prevents page breaking
outerlinewidth=0.5pt,
innertopmargin=0.5\baselineskip,
innerbottommargin=0.75\baselineskip,
innerrightmargin=11pt,
innerleftmargin=11pt]
    \begin{center}
  Top left\hfill Top Right\\
        {\Huge\textsc{This is the Title\strut}}\\
  Bottom Left\hfill Bottom Right
    \end{center}
\end{mdframed}}
\begin{document}
\createtitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

No need to use `mdframed`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\fbox{%
  \parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}{%
    \setlength{\topsep}{0.2\topsep}
    Math 7H\hfill Professor: Padraic Bartlett\par
    \begin{center}\large
    Lecture 4: Induction, the Euler Characteristic and Chemistry
    \end{center}
    \textit{Week 4}\hfill\textit{UCSB 2015}
  }%
}

\end{document}
```

[image]